# Is there a good layout convention for cron files?

Tags: cron, best-practices

I'm currently confronted with a cron file that contains a dozen different applications' tasks--some have only one, some have lots. I'm trying to figure out a good way to organize and document these processes. Are there any conventions out there that I could emulate or am I stuck making something up?

Answer (score 8):

```
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    who     command

## Acme Anvil Application
# clear logs every 5 minutes
*/5     *       *       *       *       root    /path/to/clear_logs
# monthly maintenance
30      5       1       *       *       root    /path/to/acme/maintenance

## Fabricam
# adjust timing
*/30    0-5     *       *       *       fab    /path/to/bin/fab_time

## Etc...
```

Comment: ...and if spacing out the elements is too extreme for you, at least put `# m h  dom mon dow   command`

Answer (score 5):

If your system supports /etc/cron.d, you may also try breaking up the cron jobs into individual files, grouped by application.

```
root@linuxbox:/etc/cron.d# ls
sa-update  sysstat  vnstat
```

Note that the format of cron jobs in /etc/cron.d is a little different, in that you would put the user running the command in between the time fields and the command itself, e.g.,

```
root@linuxbox:/etc/cron.d# cat sa-update
### OPTIONAL: Spamassassin Rules Updates ###
#
# http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/RuleUpdates
# Highly recommended that you read the documentation before using this.
# ENABLE UPDATES AT YOUR OWN RISK.
#
# /var/log/sa-update.log contains a history log of sa-update runs

10 4 * * * root /usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/sa-update.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend ensuring that you have a comment at the end of your /etc/crontab file. Many implementations of cron won't fire off the last job in the file if it's not terminated with a Line Feed.

Debian Lenny being one of them.

Comment: Interesting point.  I edit my crontab with vim, which won't let me create a text file without a terminating newline unless I ask it very nicely.  (Text files without a newline on the last line can cause a lot of problems.)

Comment: Sadly, not everyone uses Vi.....

Answer (score 0):

Great question. A few I have benefitted from:

#### 0) Header comment

Add useful comments that will help you write entries, and reduce the chance of jobs not working as expected.

```
##------------------------------------------------------------
## (-) Characters to escape: %, $
## (-) Logs (on Linux) are located under /var/spool/mail/ (postfix needs to be installed)
##
## Min  Hour Day  Mon  Weekday
## *    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
## ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
## │    │    │    │    └─  Weekday  (0=Sun .. 6=Sat)
## │    │    │    └──────  Month    (1..12)
## │    │    └───────────  Day      (1..31)
## │    └────────────────  Hour     (0..23)
## └─────────────────────  Minute   (0..59)
##
##------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### 1) Order

Order your entries by time of the day (morning at the top, evening at bottom)

- Rationale: it's easier to find the entry you wish to tweak.

#### 2) PATH

2. Explicitly set the PATH at the top of the file

   - Rationale: avoid "no such file or directory" errors (particularly if you need GNU versions of tools rather than Mac builtins!)

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
PATH=/Volumes/apps/homebrew/Cellar/findutils/4.9.0/libexec/gnubin/:/Volumes/apps/homebrew/Cellar/coreutils/9.1/libexec/gnubin/:/Volumes/apps/homebrew/Cellar/findutils/4.9.0/libexec/gnubin/:/opt/local/bin/:
```

#### 3) Limit sh /path/to/script.sh

Do not call scripts unless you really have to (it's better to call primitives directly in the crontab file)

- Rationale: you can quickly find the entry responsible for certain behaviour

#### 4) Backup crontab

Add the following entry (do the same in the root's crontab):

```
@weekly   crontab -l > ~/crontab.`whoami`.`date -I`.txt
```

- Rationale: whenever you reinstall your OS, you can't easily rebuild your crontab.

#### 5) | tee /tmp/cron_*log

Write the output of each entry to a log file on a ramdisk;

```
| tee /tmp/cron_*.log
| tee /tmp/cron_*.err.log
```

Rationale:

- easier to find errors in crons (e.g. `tail /tmp/cron_*.err.log`)
- junk log files don't accumulate beyond their useful life
- no need to use the built in /var/mail/messages which gets bloated

#### 6) tab after cron expression

- Rationale: Some cron expressions will be longer than others, so starting all commands in the same character column will look neater (and help you compare different commands)

```
6  12 * * 5     echo "hello"
10 12 * * 1-5   echo "world"
```

### Other

- Start with a blank crontab every year (so that cruft gets weeded out periodically)